# How to draw Feynman diagrams with vertex dotted as in the picture

Tags: feynman, feynmf

I would like to draw Feynman diagrams using `Feynmf`.

However, I cannot find a way to have a dot in the middle of wavy lines just like the picture below.
Moreover, I cannot find a way to draw a circle either.

[image]Could anyone please help me?

For example, the code I tried for the first picture on `N=1` is the following:

```
\begin{fmffile}{afilename}
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
\fmfleft{i1}
\fmfright{o1}
\fmf{photon}{i1,v1,o1}
\fmfdotn{v}{1}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
```

However, this code does not yield a middle dot that I want to draw.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that, yes, this is possible *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me" that show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). I recommend having a look at the [tikz-feynman](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman) package.

Comment: Have you seen these examples? http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/~taku/osx/feynmp/fmfsamples.pdf or here https://wiki.physik.uzh.ch/cms/latex:feynman

Comment: Please can you add a minimal working example with all packages starting from \documentclass?